# HornetQ Corrupt GZIP trailer

Tags: java, heap-memory, gzip, hornetq, corrupt

I have a problem with Hornetq 2.3.15 
java.util.zip.ZipException: Corrupt GZIP trailer
with org.apache.cxf.interceptor.Fault: Java heap space

Any Idea?

Answer (score 0):

The Problem is in the org.hornetq.utils.DeflaterReader, where byte[] readBuffer = new byte[2 * len]; So you have to be careful with setting the size of the property minLargeMessageSize, because you can get a Java heap space!